# Strange behaviour with a CTE involving two joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, common-table-expression, distinct-on

This post has been totally rephrased in order to make the question more understandable.

**Settings**
`PostgreSQL 9.5` running on `Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS`.

**Data model**

I have dataset tables, where I store data separately (time series), all those tables must share the same structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(
    Id                  SERIAL                          NOT NULL,
    ChannelId           INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
    GranulityIdIn       INTEGER,
    GranulityId         INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
    TimeValue           TIMESTAMP                       NOT NULL,
    FloatValue          FLOAT                           DEFAULT(NULL),
    Status              BIGINT                          DEFAULT(NULL),
    QualityCodeId       INTEGER                         NOT NULL,
    DataArray           FLOAT[]                         DEFAULT(NULL),
    DataCount           BIGINT                          DEFAULT(NULL),
    Performance         FLOAT                           DEFAULT(NULL),
    StepCount           INTEGER                         NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
    TableRegClass       regclass                        NOT NULL,
    Updated             TIMESTAMP                       NOT NULL,
    Tags                TEXT[]                          DEFAULT(NULL),
    --
    CONSTRAINT          PK_%s                           PRIMARY KEY(Id),
    CONSTRAINT          FK_%s_Channel                   FOREIGN KEY(ChannelId)          REFERENCES scientific.Channel(Id),
    CONSTRAINT          FK_%s_GranulityIn               FOREIGN KEY(GranulityIdIn)      REFERENCES quality.Granulity(Id),
    CONSTRAINT          FK_%s_Granulity                 FOREIGN KEY(GranulityId)        REFERENCES quality.Granulity(Id),
    CONSTRAINT          FK_%s_QualityCode               FOREIGN KEY(QualityCodeId)      REFERENCES quality.QualityCode(Id),
    CONSTRAINT          UQ_%s                           UNIQUE(QualityCodeId, ChannelId, GranulityId, TimeValue)
);

CREATE INDEX IDX_%s_Channel   ON %s USING btree(ChannelId);
CREATE INDEX IDX_%s_Quality   ON %s USING btree(QualityCodeId);
CREATE INDEX IDX_%s_Granulity ON %s USING btree(GranulityId) WHERE GranulityId > 2;
CREATE INDEX IDX_%s_TimeValue ON %s USING btree(TimeValue);
```

This definition comes from a `FUNCTION`, thus `%s` stands for the dataset name.

The `UNIQUE` constraint ensure that there must not have duplicate records within a given dataset. A record in this dataset is a value (`floatvalue`) for a given channel (`channelid`), sampled at given time (`timevalue`) on a given interval (`granulityid`), with a given quality (`qualitycodeid`). Whatever the value is, there cannot have a duplicate of `(channelid, timevalue, granulityid, qualitycodeid)`.

Records in dataset look like:

```
1;25;;1;"2015-01-01 00:00:00";0.54;160;6;"";;;0;"datastore.rtu";"2016-05-07 16:38:29.28106";""
2;25;;1;"2015-01-01 00:30:00";0.49;160;6;"";;;0;"datastore.rtu";"2016-05-07 16:38:29.28106";""
3;25;;1;"2015-01-01 01:00:00";0.47;160;6;"";;;0;"datastore.rtu";"2016-05-07 16:38:29.28106";""
```

I also have another satellite table where I store significant digit for channels, this parameters can change with time. I store it in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE SVPOLFactor (
   Id                   SERIAL                  NOT NULL,
   ChannelId            INTEGER                 NOT NULL,
   StartTimestamp       TIMESTAMP               NOT NULL,
   Factor               FLOAT                   NOT NULL,
   UnitsId              VARCHAR(8)              NOT NULL,
   --
   CONSTRAINT           PK_SVPOLFactor          PRIMARY KEY(Id),
   CONSTRAINT           FK_SVPOLFactor_Units    FOREIGN KEY(UnitsId)        REFERENCES Units(Id),
   CONSTRAINT           UQ_SVPOLFactor          UNIQUE(ChannelId, StartTimestamp)
);
```

When there is a significant digit defined for a channel, a row is added to this table. Then the factor apply since this date. First records always have the sentinel value `'-infinity'::TIMESTAMP` which means: the factor applies since the beginning. Next rows must have a real defined value. If there is no row for a given channel, it means significant digit is unitary.

Records in this table look like:

```
123;277;"-infinity";0.1;"_C"
124;1001;"-infinity";0.01;"-"
125;1001;"2014-03-01 00:00:00";0.1;"-"
126;1001;"2014-06-01 00:00:00";1;"-"
127;1001;"2014-09-01 00:00:00";10;"-"
5001;5181;"-infinity";0.1;"ug/m3"
```

**Goal**

My goal is to perform an comparison audit of two datasets that have been populated by distinct processes. To achieve it, I must:

- Compare records between dataset and assess their differences;
- Check if the difference between similar records is enclosed within the significant digit.

For this purpose, I have written the following query which behaves in a manner that I don't understand:

```
WITH

-- Join records before records (regard to uniqueness constraint) from datastore templated tables in order to make audit comparison:
S0 AS (
SELECT
    A.ChannelId
   ,A.GranulityIdIn AS gidInRef
   ,B.GranulityIdIn AS gidInAudit
   ,A.GranulityId AS GranulityId
   ,A.QualityCodeId
   ,A.TimeValue
   ,A.FloatValue AS xRef
   ,B.FloatValue AS xAudit
   ,A.StepCount AS scRef
   ,B.StepCount AS scAudit
   ,A.DataCount AS dcRef
   ,B.DataCount AS dcAudit
   ,round(A.Performance::NUMERIC, 4) AS pRef
   ,round(B.Performance::NUMERIC, 4) AS pAudit
FROM
    datastore.rtu AS A JOIN datastore.audit0 AS B USING(ChannelId, GranulityId, QualityCodeId, TimeValue)
),

-- Join before SVPOL factors in order to determine decimal factor applied to records:
S1 AS (
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON(ChannelId, TimeValue)
    S0.*
   ,SF.Factor::NUMERIC AS svpolfactor
   ,COALESCE(-log(SF.Factor), 0)::INTEGER AS k
FROM
    S0 LEFT JOIN settings.SVPOLFactor AS SF ON ((S0.ChannelId = SF.ChannelId) AND (SF.StartTimestamp <= S0.TimeValue))
ORDER BY
    ChannelId, TimeValue, StartTimestamp DESC
),

-- Audit computation:
S2 AS (
SELECT
    S1.*
   ,xaudit - xref AS dx
   ,(xaudit - xref)/NULLIF(xref, 0) AS rdx
   ,round(xaudit*pow(10, k))*pow(10, -k) AS xroundfloat
   ,round(xaudit::NUMERIC, k) AS xroundnum
   ,0.5*pow(10, -k) AS epsilon
FROM S1
)

SELECT
    *
   ,ABS(dx) AS absdx
   ,ABS(rdx) AS absrdx
   ,(xroundfloat - xref) AS dxroundfloat
   ,(xroundnum - xref) AS dxroundnum
   ,(ABS(dx) - epsilon) AS dxeps
   ,(ABS(dx) - epsilon)/epsilon AS rdxeps
   ,(xroundfloat - xroundnum) AS dfround
FROM
    S2
ORDER BY
    k DESC
   ,ABS(rdx) DESC
   ,ChannelId;
```

The query may be somewhat unreadable, roughly I expect from it to:

- Join data from two datasets using uniqueness constraint to compare similar records and compute difference (`S0`);
- For each difference, find the significant digit (`LEFT JOIN`) that applies for the current timestamps (`S1`);
- Perform some other useful statistics (`S2` and final `SELECT`).

**Problem**

When I run the query above, I have missing rows. For example: `channelid=123` with `granulityid=4` have 12 records in common in both tables (`datastore.rtu` and `datastore.audit0`). When I perform the whole query and store it in a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`, there is less than 12 rows. Then I started investigation to understand why I have missing records and I faced a strange behaviour with `WHERE` clause. If I perform a `EXPLAIN ANALIZE` of this query, I get:

```
"Sort  (cost=332212.76..332212.77 rows=1 width=232) (actual time=6042.736..6157.235 rows=61692 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: s2.k DESC, (abs(s2.rdx)) DESC, s2.channelid"
"  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 10688kB"
"  CTE s0"
"    ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.85..332208.25 rows=1 width=84) (actual time=20.408..3894.071 rows=63635 loops=1)"
"          Merge Cond: ((a.qualitycodeid = b.qualitycodeid) AND (a.channelid = b.channelid) AND (a.granulityid = b.granulityid) AND (a.timevalue = b.timevalue))"
"          ->  Index Scan using uq_rtu on rtu a  (cost=0.43..289906.29 rows=3101628 width=52) (actual time=0.059..2467.145 rows=3102319 loops=1)"
"          ->  Index Scan using uq_audit0 on audit0 b  (cost=0.42..10305.46 rows=98020 width=52) (actual time=0.049..108.138 rows=98020 loops=1)"
"  CTE s1"
"    ->  Unique  (cost=4.37..4.38 rows=1 width=148) (actual time=4445.865..4509.839 rows=61692 loops=1)"
"          ->  Sort  (cost=4.37..4.38 rows=1 width=148) (actual time=4445.863..4471.002 rows=63635 loops=1)"
"                Sort Key: s0.channelid, s0.timevalue, sf.starttimestamp DESC"
"                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 5624kB"
"                ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=0.03..4.36 rows=1 width=148) (actual time=4102.842..4277.641 rows=63635 loops=1)"
"                      Hash Cond: (sf.channelid = s0.channelid)"
"                      Join Filter: (sf.starttimestamp <= s0.timevalue)"
"                      ->  Seq Scan on svpolfactor sf  (cost=0.00..3.68 rows=168 width=20) (actual time=0.013..0.083 rows=168 loops=1)"
"                      ->  Hash  (cost=0.02..0.02 rows=1 width=132) (actual time=4102.002..4102.002 rows=63635 loops=1)"
"                            Buckets: 65536 (originally 1024)  Batches: 2 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 3841kB"
"                            ->  CTE Scan on s0  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=132) (actual time=20.413..4038.078 rows=63635 loops=1)"
"  CTE s2"
"    ->  CTE Scan on s1  (cost=0.00..0.07 rows=1 width=168) (actual time=4445.910..4972.832 rows=61692 loops=1)"
"  ->  CTE Scan on s2  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=1 width=232) (actual time=4445.934..5312.884 rows=61692 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 1.782 ms"
"Execution time: 6201.148 ms"
```

And I know that I must have 67106 rows instead.

At the time of writing, I know that `S0` returns the correct amount of rows. Therefore the problem must lies in further `CTE`.

What I find really strange is that:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH

S0 AS (
SELECT * FROM datastore.audit0
),

S1 AS (
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON(ChannelId, TimeValue)
    S0.*
   ,SF.Factor::NUMERIC AS svpolfactor
   ,COALESCE(-log(SF.Factor), 0)::INTEGER AS k
FROM
    S0 LEFT JOIN settings.SVPOLFactor AS SF ON ((S0.ChannelId = SF.ChannelId) AND (SF.StartTimestamp <= S0.TimeValue))
ORDER BY
    ChannelId, TimeValue, StartTimestamp DESC
)

SELECT * FROM S1 WHERE Channelid=123 AND GranulityId=4 -- POST-FILTERING
```

returns 10 rows:

```
"CTE Scan on s1  (cost=24554.34..24799.39 rows=1 width=196) (actual time=686.211..822.803 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  Filter: ((channelid = 123) AND (granulityid = 4))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 94890"
"  CTE s0"
"    ->  Seq Scan on audit0  (cost=0.00..2603.20 rows=98020 width=160) (actual time=0.009..26.092 rows=98020 loops=1)"
"  CTE s1"
"    ->  Unique  (cost=21215.99..21951.14 rows=9802 width=176) (actual time=590.337..705.070 rows=94900 loops=1)"
"          ->  Sort  (cost=21215.99..21461.04 rows=98020 width=176) (actual time=590.335..665.152 rows=99151 loops=1)"
"                Sort Key: s0.channelid, s0.timevalue, sf.starttimestamp DESC"
"                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 12376kB"
"                ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=5.78..4710.74 rows=98020 width=176) (actual time=0.143..346.949 rows=99151 loops=1)"
"                      Hash Cond: (s0.channelid = sf.channelid)"
"                      Join Filter: (sf.starttimestamp <= s0.timevalue)"
"                      ->  CTE Scan on s0  (cost=0.00..1960.40 rows=98020 width=160) (actual time=0.012..116.543 rows=98020 loops=1)"
"                      ->  Hash  (cost=3.68..3.68 rows=168 width=20) (actual time=0.096..0.096 rows=168 loops=1)"
"                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 12kB"
"                            ->  Seq Scan on svpolfactor sf  (cost=0.00..3.68 rows=168 width=20) (actual time=0.006..0.045 rows=168 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.385 ms"
"Execution time: 846.179 ms"
```

And the next one returns the correct amount of rows:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH

S0 AS (
SELECT * FROM datastore.audit0
WHERE Channelid=123 AND GranulityId=4 -- PRE FILTERING
),

S1 AS (
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON(ChannelId, TimeValue)
    S0.*
   ,SF.Factor::NUMERIC AS svpolfactor
   ,COALESCE(-log(SF.Factor), 0)::INTEGER AS k
FROM
    S0 LEFT JOIN settings.SVPOLFactor AS SF ON ((S0.ChannelId = SF.ChannelId) AND (SF.StartTimestamp <= S0.TimeValue))
ORDER BY
    ChannelId, TimeValue, StartTimestamp DESC
)

SELECT * FROM S1
```

Where:

```
"CTE Scan on s1  (cost=133.62..133.86 rows=12 width=196) (actual time=0.580..0.598 rows=12 loops=1)"
"  CTE s0"
"    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on audit0  (cost=83.26..128.35 rows=12 width=160) (actual time=0.401..0.423 rows=12 loops=1)"
"          Recheck Cond: ((channelid = 123) AND (granulityid = 4))"
"          Heap Blocks: exact=12"
"          ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=83.26..83.26 rows=12 width=0) (actual time=0.394..0.394 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_audit0_channel  (cost=0.00..11.12 rows=377 width=0) (actual time=0.055..0.055 rows=377 loops=1)"
"                      Index Cond: (channelid = 123)"
"                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_audit0_granulity  (cost=0.00..71.89 rows=3146 width=0) (actual time=0.331..0.331 rows=3120 loops=1)"
"                      Index Cond: (granulityid = 4)"
"  CTE s1"
"    ->  Unique  (cost=5.19..5.28 rows=12 width=176) (actual time=0.576..0.581 rows=12 loops=1)"
"          ->  Sort  (cost=5.19..5.22 rows=12 width=176) (actual time=0.576..0.576 rows=12 loops=1)"
"                Sort Key: s0.channelid, s0.timevalue, sf.starttimestamp DESC"
"                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 20kB"
"                ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=0.39..4.97 rows=12 width=176) (actual time=0.522..0.552 rows=12 loops=1)"
"                      Hash Cond: (sf.channelid = s0.channelid)"
"                      Join Filter: (sf.starttimestamp <= s0.timevalue)"
"                      ->  Seq Scan on svpolfactor sf  (cost=0.00..3.68 rows=168 width=20) (actual time=0.006..0.022 rows=168 loops=1)"
"                      ->  Hash  (cost=0.24..0.24 rows=12 width=160) (actual time=0.446..0.446 rows=12 loops=1)"
"                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 6kB"
"                            ->  CTE Scan on s0  (cost=0.00..0.24 rows=12 width=160) (actual time=0.403..0.432 rows=12 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.448 ms"
"Execution time: 4.510 ms"
```

Thus the problem seems to lie in `S1`. There is no significant digit defined for `channelid = 123`, therefore, those records should not be generated without the `LEFT JOIN`. But this does not explain why there are some missing.

**Questions**

- **What am I doing wrong in this query?**

I use `LEFT JOIN` in order to keep correct cardinality when I fetch significant digits, therefore it must not remove records, after that it is just arithmetic.

- **How can pre-filtering returning more rows than post-filtering?**

This sounds a little bit buggy to me. If I do not use `WHERE` clauses, all records (or combination) are generated (I know that `JOIN` is a `WHERE` clause) and then computation occurs. When I do not use additional `WHERE` (original query), I miss rows (like showed in the examples). When I add a WHERE clause to filter, results are different (which may be fine, if post-filtering has returned more records than pre-filtering).

Any constructive answer that points out my mistakes and miscomprehension of the query are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: of course isnt possible. Maybe you have some `NULL` values on your conditions. Would be better if you include the join query so we can understand your `cond1` and `cond2`

Comment: This is not for a simple query like the one you showed, you should add your actual Select

Comment: No there is NULL value in my condition because, they are on column that are FOREIGN KEY, NOT NULL and share an UNQIUE CONSTRAINT

Comment: Then show us your db schemas so we can understand your problem better.

Comment: @dnoeth, the point is, when I perform the query on tables A and B there are missing rows. When I subsample for A and B, and then run the query row are not missing. Then I filtered out my first query and adding a AND clause at the end, increase the number of rows.

Comment: Without your actual query there's no way to help you.

Comment: jlandercy, This is impossible to know without seeing the actual code!

Comment: you said `The query joins two tables`. Which query joins two tables? `SELECT * FROM a WHERE (cond1) AND (cond2)` does not join two tables so there is information missing from your question. I am not asking to view your tables (60 000 000 rows would be too much to view). I asking to view the actual query you are executing. It can't be as simple as `SELECT * FROM a WHERE (cond1) AND (cond2)` because you yourself mentioned "The query joins two tables".

Comment: Now, after you provided us the query, which condition is adding records when you add it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, this will be replaced by a string (because it comes from a function). By the way, my query run and returns, there is no SQL Error syntax here. This is not the point

Comment: I can't tell from what you added which two specific queries you are talking about returning more records, They are not querying the same tables.

Comment: @HLGEM provided A and B, they have 12 record in commun, it must return 12 records, no where clause, jointure over Unique constraint. When doing the jointure on whole tables (>60 000 000 records each) There are missing record. If I extract records, from both tables to another table, and I rerun, there are then correct amount. Please check commented WHERE clause in the example

Comment: Does the changed `WHERE` clause change the **overall** result or only the rows for the first CTE?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I know about JOIN cardinality, it is WHY I always check my row count. Please read the WHERE clause commented. When I filter my huge table, adding a AND condition increase the number of row. This is a strange behaviour, don't you think?

Comment: @DanGetz, When I only perform S0, I have the same issue, missing rows, but then if I filter out, WHERE agrees to 12 rows both.

Comment: Check if both plans are identical.

Comment: @dnoeth You mean EXPLAIN ANALYZE, in case where an index is corrupted?

Comment: I just have destroyed one of my table that I suspect to be corrupted. I will regenerate it to see if it applies. I post details tomorrow. Thank you anyway

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, question have been rephrased and it integrated user comments.

Comment: @dnoeth, question have been rephrased and it integrated user comments

Comment: @DanGetz, question have been rephrased and it integrated user comments

Comment: @HLGEM, question have been rephrased and it integrated user comments

Comment: I'm not a PG guy, so probably not really helpful. But I'm a bit confused , because I would expect an error message regarding *ambiguous* column names for *DISTINCT ON(**ChannelId**, TimeValue)* (and in the `ORDER BY`, too). Is this PG specific, does it automatically pick the column from the 1st table? In both Explains it's from `S0`, but just in case, can you qualify it to `S0.ChannelId`?

Comment: @jlandercy thank you for putting in the names of the `rtu` and `audit0` tables into your query. Now it's a little clearer to me what you're doing. But in your edits you removed all `WHERE` clauses from your query. Are they the same as before your edits (in `S0`)?

Comment: It's also unclear why you feel you should have 67106 rows returned, when `S0` returns 63635 in the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What's happening

You're probably missing rows because of the `DISTINCT ON` clause in `S1`. It appears you're using this to pick only the most recent applicable rows of `SVPOLFactor`. However, you wrote

```
DISTINCT ON(ChannelId, TimeValue)
```

while in the query `S0`, unique rows could also differ by `GranulityId` and/or `QualityCodeId`. So, for example, if you had rows in both `rtu` and `audit0` with the following columns:

```
 Id | ChannelId | GranulityId |      TimeValue      | QualityCodeid 
----|-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------
  1 |       123 |           4 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 |             2
  2 |       123 |           5 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 |             2
```

then `S0` with no `WHERE` filtering would return rows for both of these, because they differ in `GranulityId`. But one of these would be dropped by the `DISTINCT ON` clause in `S1`, because they have the same values for `ChannelId` and `TimeValue`. Even worse, because you only ever sort by `ChannelId` and `TimeValue`, which row is picked and which is dropped is not determined by anything in your query—it's left to chance!

In your example of "post-filtering" `WHERE ChannelId = 123 AND GranulityId = 4`, both these rows are in `S0`. Then it's possible, depending on an ordering that you aren't really in control of, for the `DISTINCT ON` in `S1` to filter out row 1 instead of row 2. Then, row 2 is filtered out at the end, leaving you with *neither* of the rows. The mistake in the `DISTINCT ON` clause caused row 2, which you didn't even want to see, to eliminate row 1 in an intermediate query.

In your example of "pre-filtering" in `S0`, you filter out row 2 before it can interfere with row 1, so row 1 makes it to the final query.

## A fix

One way to stop these rows from being excluded would be to expand the `DISTINCT ON` and `ORDER BY` clauses to include `GranulityId` and `QualityCodeId`:

```
DISTINCT ON(ChannelId, TimeValue, GranulityId, QualityCodeId)
-- ...
ORDER BY ChannelId, TimeValue, GranulityId, QualityCodeId, StartTimestamp DESC
```

Of course, if you filter the results of `S0` so that they all have the same values for some of these columns, you can omit those in the `DISTINCT ON`. In your example of pre-filtering `S0` with `ChannelId` and `GranulityId`, this could be:

```
DISTINCT ON(TimeValue, QualityCodeId)
-- ...
ORDER BY TimeValue, QualityCodeId, StartTimestamp DESC
```

But I doubt you'd save much time doing this, so it's probably safest to keep all those columns, in case you change the query again some day and forget to change the `DISTINCT ON`.

---

I want to mention that [the PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-DISTINCT) warn about these sorts of problems with `DISTINCT ON` (emphasis mine):

> A set of rows for which all the [`DISTINCT ON`] expressions are equal are considered duplicates, and only the first row of the set is kept in the output. Note that the "first row" of a set is **unpredictable unless the query is sorted on enough columns to guarantee a unique ordering** of the rows arriving at the `DISTINCT` filter. (`DISTINCT ON` processing occurs after `ORDER BY` sorting.)
>
> The `DISTINCT ON` clause is not part of the SQL standard and is sometimes considered bad style because of the **potentially indeterminate** nature of its results. With judicious use of `GROUP BY` and subqueries in `FROM`, this construct can be avoided, but it is often the most convenient alternative.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I was mistaken about the order of clause resolution. I don't know why I have assumed that DISTINCT clause came first than JOIN (I know FROM come first and DISTINCT on come after ORDER BY, I just forget about it). It works now, and I will get rid of this DISTINCT, using a sub-query as PG API suggests.

Answer (score 2):

You already got a correct answer, this is just an addition. When you calculate start/end in a Derived Table, the join returns a single row and you don't need `DISTINCT ON` (and this might be more efficient, too):

```
...
FROM S0 LEFT JOIN
 ( 
   SELECT *,
      -- find the next StartTimestamp = End of the current period 
      COALESCE(LEAD(StartTimestamp) 
               OVER (PARTITION BY ChannelId
                     ORDER BY StartTimestamp, '+infinity') AS EndTimestamp
   FROM SVPOLFactor AS t
 ) AS SF 
ON  (S0.ChannelId = SF.ChannelId)
AND (S0.TimeValue >= SF.StartTimestamp)
AND (S0.TimeValue < SF.EndTimestamp)
```

Comment: This is how I final solved my problem, I have created a VIEW using lateral query. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

They are really two logically different queries because of the different order of operations `DISTINCT ON(ChannelId, TimeValue) ... ORDER BY ChannelId, TimeValue, StartTimestamp`  and `WHERE Channelid=123 AND GranulityId=4` . Look at

```
create table sample(
  distinctkey int,
  orderkey int,
  valkey int
);

 insert into sample (distinctkey,orderkey,valkey)
 select 1,10,150
 union all
 select 1,20,100;
```

And two queries similar to yours:

```
select distinctkey, orderkey, valkey
from (
  select distinct on(distinctkey) distinctkey, orderkey, valkey
  from sample 
  order by distinctkey, orderkey) t
where distinctkey = 1 and valkey = 100;
```

returns no rows. While

```
select distinct on(distinctkey) distinctkey, orderkey, valkey
from (
  select distinctkey, orderkey,valkey
  from sample 
  where distinctkey = 1 and valkey = 100) t
order by distinctkey, orderkey;
```

returns 1 row.

The same way your queries may return different number of rows depending on data. You should choose only one which logic is relevant for the task you are facing.